# exec convert works on SSH fine but not in script

Tags: php

I have this script to convert PDF to images

```
$targetPath = 'test.pdf';    
$location   = "/usr/local/bin/convert";
$randomNum   = time();
$nameto     = $randomNum.".jpg";
$convert    = $location. " -density 150 " . $targetPath . " " . $nameto;

exec($convert);
```

where $convert is something like

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -density 150 PATH/test-1430326864.pdf PATH/1430326864.jpg
```

when I execute this command on SSH, it gives desired output, but in php script it doesn't convert PDF to images. But this same script convert some of PDF to images successfully, but not all PDFs to images

is there any issue in script or how can I fix this, so every PDF convert successfully?

UPDATE:

Changed exec code.. in php script to

```
exec($convert, $output);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
die();
```

then, got this following output

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "Error: /invalidfont in /findfont"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Operand stack:"
  [2]=>
  string(97) "   --dict:7/16(L)--   F0   9.602   FontObject   --dict:9/9(L)--   --dict:9/9(L)--   Arial   Arial"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Execution stack:"
  [4]=>
  string(672) "   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1846   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   1829   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   8   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1804   8   9   %oparray_pop"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "Dictionary stack:"
  [6]=>
  string(199) "   --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--"
  [7]=>
  string(32) "Current allocation mode is local"
  [8]=>
  string(16) "Last OS error: 2"
}
```

hope this will help to find solution for this problem!

Comment: I would first check `phpinfo()` to see if (for security reasons) the exec command is not enabled.  Beyond that, check logs for web server or php, lastly, turn on error reporting.

Comment: exec is already enabled. see here http://prntscr.com/6zlvxp

Comment: You most likely need to use `putenv` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php in order for the external program to find all the binaries, paths etc that it needs to operate. Because from skimming through it looks like it doesn't find the font that it needs.

Comment: Yes, @Torxed right, fonts are missing or not loaded.we've contacted server support for this.